# do.call vs rbind, keeping rownames

Tags: r

When using `rbind` vs `do.call(rbind, x)`. Why and how does the `do.call` operation maintain the parent list names and not `rbind`?

Also, if I would like to replicate the behaviour of do.call within rbind, by retrieving the parent list name and pass it along as the row-name, how could this be done as smooth as possible?

Comment: i think this could be much improved with a simple example

Comment: `rbind` and `do.call` are two completely separate and different operations.  I'm not sure what you're asking here.  There are two other args to `rbind`, which are `deparse.level` and `make.row.names` (for data frames only) that you may wish to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a named list:

```
(l <- list(a=data.frame(x=1, y=2), b=data.frame(x=2, y=3)))
# $a
#   x y
# 1 1 2
# 
# $b
#   x y
# 1 2 3
```

As you note, `do.call` with `rbind` passes the names of the list elements, which results in row names for your combined data frame:

```
do.call(rbind, l)
#   x y
# a 1 2
# b 2 3
```

To get these names using `rbind` alone, all you need to do is to provide named arguments to that function:

```
rbind(a=l[["a"]], b=l[["b"]])
#   x y
# a 1 2
# b 2 3
```